# Replacing localhost with IP address in webservice

Tags: c#, android, wcf, web-services

I have a wcf service to connect a C# server with Android. 
When I run it from the navigator with `localhost:38300/EmployeeInfo.svc/GetEmployee/?key=11` it works, but when I replace `localhost` with my IP address, I run into this error:

> Bad Request Invalid Hostname

I have to change it, to use it from the Android Emulator. How can it be fixed?

Comment: can you ping that ip address?

Comment: did you tried it with prefix http:// ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the Visual Studio Development server. This is a very limited web server that cannot be accessed from outside your host. You should host your WCF service in IIS.